# How to click a link in WebDriver using Python?

Tags: python, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
<tr><td class=wb><a href="javascript:void(fight())" style='text-decoration:none'><b>Click here!</a></td></tr>
```

Hi, how to click this url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but try this:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")
for element in elements:
    if element.text == "Click here!":
        element.click()
```

Or:

```
elements  = find_elements_by_class_name("wb")
for element in elements:
    if element.text == "Click here!":
        element.click()
```

Comment: You shouldn't try to get all the elements. Instead, you should only retrieve the first element, which you can easily do with a single line of code.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have used:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Click here!").click()
```